# Getting Error in auto_rote packages in flutter

Tags: flutter, routes, flutter-routes

I try to regenerate auto routes.
I try this command `flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --delete-conflicting-output`

[image: Getting this logs continuously]

Comment: You havn't presented an error... Could you update the question with the error?

Comment: This console log continuously showing is the error.

Comment: That is not an error. That is information for you about what is going on. As an example, here is my own output from my project running the same command: 
`[INFO] 10.3s elapsed, 24/40 actions completed. [INFO] 11.4s elapsed, 24/40 actions completed. [INFO] 12.4s elapsed, 24/40 actions completed.`
Eventually it becomes: `[INFO] 1m 7s elapsed, 2091/2091 actions completed. [INFO] 1m 8s elapsed, 2464/2467 actions completed. [INFO] Running build completed, took 1m 8s`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the "s" at the end, like this:
"flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs"

Answer (score 0):

First update your dependencies

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

after that run

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```